# Why sun.management.OperatingSystemImpl is package visible?

Tags: java, sun, mxbean

This class has really helpful methods. I can call them by reflection.
But why I forced to do it?

I would like to cast OperatingSystemMXBean to OperatingSystemImpl and call them normal way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The class seems public, at least it does in [http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/management/OperatingSystemImpl.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/management/OperatingSystemImpl.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you explain why you would like to cast `OperatingSystemMXBean` to `OperatingSystemImpl` since `OperatingSystemImpl implements OperatingSystemMXBean`.

you can use it

```
    java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean os = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    System.out.println(os.getArch());
```

or

```
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory
            .getPlatformMXBean(com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean.class);
    System.out.println(osBean.getProcessCpuLoad() * 100);
    System.out.println(osBean.getSystemCpuLoad() * 100);
```

Comment: I do not need os.getArch(). I need os.getSystemCpuLoad()